# How do I set up a Rails Angular project to test JS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, angularjs, asset-pipeline, jasmine

I am trying to set up my Rails Angular project to provide JS tests. I have tried almost everything that I have found on Google:

- [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/) (formerly Testacular)
- [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine) + [Jasmine-headless-WebKit](https://github.com/johnbintz/jasmine-headless-webkit)
- [Jasminerice](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice)
- some other tutorials

but I failed with all of them. I'm looking for a way to run unit and e2e tests in the most painless way (it can be in Guard or Karma, I don't care, but it must run it automatically in the background).

Does anyone have some nice article with a nice example of how to achieve this? In my research I have found [this](https://github.com/lucassus/rails-angular-seed), but IMHO it is an example of how to NOT do this.

My actual `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Use Ruby 1.9.3 instead default Heroku's 1.9.2
# for development I suggest https://gist.github.com/1688857
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'

# Use PostgreSQL, which is quite awesome, fast and easy
gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1'

  # I heard that you like Compass
  gem 'compass'

  # Angular.js
  gem 'angularjs-rails'
  gem 'angularjs-rails-resource'
  gem 'angular-ui-rails'

  # Assets should be minified before production
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Serve static pages like a boss
gem 'high_voltage'

# Some user management will be nice
gem 'devise' # User management
# gem 'cancan' # And they privileges

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
gem 'jbuilder'

# Be fast and deadly as Puma
#gem 'puma'

# We need also some administration panel, don't we?
gem 'rails_admin'

# Some helpers
gem 'andand'

group :development do
  # IRb is ugly. Use Pry for the God's sake
  gem 'pry-rails'

  # Deploy with Capistrano
  # gem 'capistrano'
  # or Vlad the Deployer
  # gem 'vlad'

  # Why bother yourself with rerunning tests? Use Guard
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-livereload'
  gem 'guard-jasmine'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', require: false
  gem 'rb-inotify', require: false

  # Who like ugly error pages? We don't.
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'

  # Prettier documentation
  gem 'yard'
end

group :development, :test do
  # Use RSpec for testing
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.12.0'

  # Test JS using Jasmine
  gem 'jasmine'
  gem 'jasmine-headless-webkit'

  # Some DB table generator
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 4.1.0'

  # And fake data generator
  gem 'ffaker'
end

group :test do
  # Some Gherkins will be also good (to vodka of course)
  gem 'turnip', '~> 1.1.0'

  # Aww, an of course some web browser will be also apprised
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.0.1'

  # Clean DB after tests
  gem 'database_cleaner'

  # Some nice matchers
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'

  # Extend your mocks
  gem 'bourne', '~> 1.2.1'

  # Coverage reports will be nice
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end
```

**PS:**
It would be nice if I can create coverage reports in a simple way.

Comment: "but it must run it automatically in background" - we created test runners that ran off `Grunt` for our Angular project and these created coverage reports and xUnit outputs for CI (such as Jenkins); so does it matter that you have to run these tests from a `Gemfile` or can you throw some `nodejs` into the mix?

Comment: It will be nice to have it in `Gemfile` to integrate that with Guard, but I'm not forced to that. Maybe even better will it be if I separate frontend tests from backend tests. So Grunt/Karma option is also nice. But I also want to have all tests in `spec/` directory (if it is possible).

Comment: I'm trying out https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon this weekend, will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [teaspoon](https://github.com/modeset/teaspoon) it runs your favorite test suite (default is jasmine) and they have a wiki to integrate with angular. Teaspoon integrates with the asset pipeline, so you can throw all the angular gems in there and require them in the teaspoon generated spec_helper.js.

The other cool thing is: they have a guard plugin available as well.

Answer (score 6):

I feel your pain, it took me a bit of trial and error to get all tests running for my Rails app. I ended up using Guard for developer continuous testing for specs, acceptance, and javascripts. Here are the fruits of my labor.

This is the *Gemfile* snippet you will need to include. It has the required Gems for [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), [Jasmine](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/), [Rspec](http://rspec.info/), and [Turnip](https://github.com/jnicklas/turnip). This setup will work with MRI and JRuby, we run our tests on both.

```
group :test, :development do
  # Guard
  gem 'guard-jasmine'
  gem "guard-bundler", ">= 1.0.0"
  gem "guard-rails", ">= 0.4.0"
  gem "guard-rspec", ">= 2.5.2"
  gem "rb-inotify", ">= 0.9.0", :require => false
  gem "rb-fsevent", ">= 0.9.3", :require => false
  gem "rb-fchange", ">= 0.0.6", :require => false

  # Rspec
  gem "rspec-rails", '~> 2.12.2'

  # Jasmine
  gem "jasmine", '~> 1.3.1'
  gem "jasminerice"
end

group :test do
  # Turnip
  gem "turnip", '~> 1.1.0'
  gem "capybara", '~> 2.0.3'
end
```

This the full *Guardfile* that watches Rspec, Turnip, and Jasmine to trigger tests:

```
guard 'rspec' do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$})     { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }

  # Rails 
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$})                           { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.*)(\.erb|\.haml)$})                 { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}#{m[2]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$})                  { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb')                           { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb')  { "spec/controllers" }

  # Turnip features and steps
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/(.+)\.feature$})
  watch(%r{^spec/acceptance/steps/(.+)_steps\.rb$})   { |m| Dir[File.join("**/#{m[1]}.feature")][0] || 'spec/acceptance' }
end

guard :jasmine do
  watch(%r{spec/javascripts/spec\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$}) { 'spec/javascripts' }
  watch(%r{spec/javascripts/.+_spec\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)$})
  watch(%r{spec/javascripts/fixtures/.+$})
  watch(%r{app/assets/javascripts/(.+?)\.(js\.coffee|js|coffee)(?:\.\w+)*$}) { |m| "spec/javascripts/#{ m[1] }_spec.#{ m[2] }" }
end
```

Now things get a little tricky. To get Jasmine to properly load up AngularJS for tests I downloaded [angular-mocks.js 1.0.7](http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular-mocks.js) to the directory *spec/javascripts/support/angular-mocks.js*. This is used by the spec helper and the jasmine config to run the AnguljarJS specs.

For the *spec/javascripts/spec_helper.js.coffee*, point it at the Rails app javascript, the angular-mocks.js, and all the javascript specs:

```
#=require ../../app/assets/javascripts/application
#=require ./support/angular-mocks
#=require_tree ./
```

For the Jasmine config, *spec/javascripts/support/jasmine.yml*, the config will need to point at the Rails app javascript and the angular-mocks.js.  Here is the  we use, but with the comments removed for brevity:

```
src_files:
  - assets/application.js
  - spec/javascripts/support/angular-mocks.js

stylesheets:
  - stylesheets/**/*.css

helpers:
  - helpers/**/*.js

spec_files:
  - '**/*[sS]pec.js'

src_dir:

spec_dir: spec/javascripts
```

With everything set up, you simply have to run `bundle exec guard` and all the tests will run and be triggered by development changes.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a blog post about a very simple way to set up AngularJS unit testing on a Rails app using the default Jasmine gem. It took a small code change to get things working smoothly, which has been accepted by the Jasmine team.

http://pivotallabs.com/unit-testing-angularjs-using-jasmine/

In an nutshell:

Add jasmine and angularjs-rails to your Gemfile

```
gem "angularjs-rails"
gem "jasmine", github: "pivotal/jasmine-gem"
```

Install the gems and run the Jasmine generator

```
$ bundle install
$ rails g jasmine:install
```

Add angular to your application.js, before the rest of your application code

```
//= require angular
//= require_tree .
```

Create a file named `./spec/javascripts/helpers/angular_helpers.js` and add this line

```
//= require angular-mocks
```

Now you can include AngularJS implementation files in your `app/assets` directory and write tests that use the provided mocks. And when you upgrade the `angularjs-rails` gem, you will get new versions of `angular.js` and `angular-mocks.js` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck checking out the [angular boilerplate project](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate) it uses grunt as the build system which I realise is not ruby in anyway, however I think when trying to test things with angular your only hope is to go the nodejs/karma route.

This setup watches for changes in your code and runs the tests. However in my limited experience I haven't been able to get it to show the results of the test run. I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong or if it is not supported.

Anyway hope this helps